# How to find positive integers of any numbers

Tags: math, integer

How many positive two-digits integers are factors of (2^24 - 1)?

Can anyone tell me the formula or some shortcuts to find positive integers?

Comment: When you say many such questions are you meaning always a power of 2 minus one or always specifically 2^24-1, etc. This is the kind of question that it could be very useful to have a bit idea of the bounds of the question...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to find factors of a number except calculating them. You have to iterate over the two-digits integers and make mod calculation.

Comment: like I will have to factorise the number given to me . then will have to count all the factor .. right?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. RSA also bases on the fact that you have to iterate to find the factors.

Comment: You don't want to factorise the number, just test all the possible factors. Factorising entirely would involve finding potentially many factors that you just don't care about which is a waste of time. And of course if you only want prime factors its even less numbers to test.

Comment: Good point - if he only ever wants two digit factors then there are only 90 to test.

Comment: i guess there is no easy way other than this :(

Answer (score 2):

There appear to be 12 *divisors* in all: 13, 15, 17, 21, 35, 39, 45, 51, 63, 65, 85 and 91.

See: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factorize+2%5E24+-+1

Comment: I'm guessing that its more than just that number he wants to solve for but until he says that then this is a good answer. Hardcoding this is by far the best solution. ;-)

Comment: @Chris: yes, there are really two questions from the OP above - I was just answering the first one, as it's a lot easier to answer for one specific case than for the more general case.

Comment: @chirs amd paul ... yes I wanted to solve more than that number ... I thought if there is any short approach so that every time i dont have to take the path of lengthy process.

Comment: i found something like this .. (googled it)


a^x * b^y = z , where a,b are prime factors and z is the number
number of factors = 2 * (x+1) * (y+1)

for exameple 147 = 3^2 * 7^2

number of factors = 2 * (x+1) * (y+1) = (2+1) * (2+1) = 18 / 2 = 9

divide by 2 to get exclude the negative factors

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a trick that I know! First you need to prime factorize the number, lets say that my number is 56. My remaining prime numbers would be 7, 2, 2, 2. Since I have three 2s, I would write 2^3. Since there is only one 7, I will write 7^1. Then, add one to each of the powers: 1+1      3+1,    and then multiply them.  1+1=2      3+1=4

4*2=8

So your for this example, the answer is 8!! Have fun!

- from a fifth grader